# Необычные дубли вопросов, SVG болезнь

Tags: обсуждение

Вот появился очередной вопрос-самоответ [Движение поезда с помощью SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788891/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-svg)

Можно убедится что это "**эпидемия анимации**" в SVG набрав поиск по тегам `[SVG] [анимация]`. Нужно метить всё дублями? Или ничего страшного - скоро система сама выяснит что к чему и вылечится? Или тема SVG это новый тренд - и она стала по-настоящему интересной?

Или возможно для авторов статей нужно выделить отдельное место (Обучение анимации SVG)?
(список старый)

- [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788891/Движение-поезда-с-помощью-svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788891/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-svg)
- [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787246/Как-нарисовать-автомобиль-с-помощью-команд-svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787246/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4-svg)
- [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763609/Анимация-наполнения-карты-контентом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763609/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC)
- [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764375/Анимация-маршрутов-самолётов-на-растровой-карте/764377#764377](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764375/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5/764377#764377)
- [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778333/Анимированный-текст-с-волной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778333/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9)
- [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769740/Как-данный-пример-анимации-css-сделать-на-чистом-svg-smil](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769740/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-css-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-svg-smil)

Почему дубли - потому что смысл вопросов одинаковый: "Есть предмет который нужно анимировать. Как это сделать" и ответ с готовым решением как правило от того же автора. Ну и высокие балы в сравнении с другими вопросами.

Думаю сейчас в 2020 году "**болезнь**" продолжается. Если набрать поиск по svg - то вопросы на первой же странице поиска имеют более высокую репутацию, 3, 2, 5, 4, 8. Если посмотреть метки [c#] [php] [python] - то там балы идут 0,1 и изредка 3,5 и больше. По факту выходит что общество SVG оценивает выше чем не SVG. Отдельные учасники входят в конфликт с другими, видимо из-за того, что кто-то считает что "**придумал картинку, придумал анимацию, решение опубликовал, профит**" - это злоупотребление механизмом SO, тем более что всё это самоответы. Возможно не все кто участвует в теме SVG набирают большие балы, что создаёт ощущение сговора, возможно ошибочное. Видит ли кто в этом проблему - возможно проблемы нету. Просто изредка по теме SVG будут небольшие локальные конфликты.

[image]

Можете для интереса отсортировать SVG по убыванию голосов и будет понятна зависть отдельный пользователей. Но пока что считается что так можно.

Comment: часть вопросов - переводы похоже

Comment: @Grundy тогда для повышение рейтинга - выгоднее всего быть переводчиком. Меня удивил вес вопросов, все и вопрос и ответ как правило имеют оценку выше 5. Но возможно это и нормальное явление. Почему бы нет.

Comment: Хорошие переводы хороших вопросов/ответов приветствуются

Comment: Тоже несколько раз обращал внимание на это. Вопросы по не особо популярным меткам, но стабильно плюсуются. Видимо просто малочисленное, но сплоченное подсообщество :)

Comment: @nick_n_ a, чем вызвано поднятие топика почти 3-x летней давности, появление новых скринов. Может я Вас чем-то нечаянно задел в темах обсуждения конкурсов?  Посмотрел Ваш профиль, ни одного вопроса - ответа по метке svg. Видимо эта не ваша специализация, поэтому Вам трудно правильно оценить силу или слабость ответов.  Дело в том, что в рунете очень мало ресурсов, литературы по SVG на русском, так как это довольно трудный скриптовый язык.. На сайтах, где есть статьи по SVG, это в основном переводы одних и тех же статей, причем щедро разбавленные рекламой.

Comment: @nick_n_a Сообщества SVG уже нет с 2018 года. Ребята научились SVG и ушли в самостоятельную коммерческую деяетельность. Новые люди конечно подключаются иногда,  заглядывают в мой спец. чат, но изучают SVG недолго , слишком труден предмет для освоения.

Comment: Конфликтом и колличеством вопросов, по поводу забаненого учасника. Раз система разрешает начислять "лишние" балы с точки зрения некоторых - значит видимо проблема с самой системой. Я предполагал что эта ситуация может привести к конфликтам - думаю решать проблему стоит по мере появления новых конфликтов. Возможно SO нужнается в чём то похожем на хабр, или возможно есть другой способ избегания конфликтных ситуаций.

Comment: @nick_n_a Вы только учтите одну вещь, - люди быстрее верят в плохое, чем в хорошее. Если вот этот забаненный участник,  говорит, что все участники конкурса злостные накрутчики, то почему-то верят этому сразу, не пытаясь даже разобраться.

Answer (score 5):

Возможно, зависит от тематики, т.к. в других я не вижу такого плотного плюсования вопросов, хоть переводов, хоть оригинальных.

С другой стороны, у нас есть активисты, которые продвигают тему SVG и даже держат [тематический чат по SVG](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat), который по мере сил популяризуют. Удаётся? Если да, то можно ставить в пример. Но тут непонятно, что положить в качестве критерия. Николас бы мерял привлечённый трафик те, кто продвигает тему - смотрели бы на число SVG-активистов; остальные бы смотрели на то, как быстро отвечается на их вопрос по теме SVG.

Лично мне тема эта не близка, поэтому писать/переводить ради большего роста репутации неинтересно.

Нужно ли какое-то спецрасследование аномалии? Лично я не вижу особого криминала в том, что есть какие-то темы более популярные, чем другие. Четыре плюса в этой тематике всегда можно набрать, по числу заинтересованных лиц.

Вот, например, ваша первая ссылка:

[image: пример с поездами]

Её постили в чат SVG, там и были первые плюсы.

Остальное - ваш пиар ;) в этой теме на мете. Пойду и я поплюсую немного )