# С какой стати вопросы и ответы помечаются как общие против воли их автора?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, общие-сообщения, авторские-права

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, с какой стати и на каком основании мои вопросы и наши ответы [помечены как общие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11132/377637)?

[Как нарисовать и анимировать символ (знак) российского рубля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1113095/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f) - это моя личная (авторская) работа. Она не может быть общей.

[Как анимировать слово StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105132/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-stackoverflow) - а здесь кто-нибудь спросил у авторов ответов, согласны ли все они, что их авторские ответы стали общими?

Как долго будет продолжаться атака на авторов?

Кроме этого, заявляю от себя лично, а также от лица участников, которые публиковали свои ответы, о грубейшем нарушении авторских прав. Площадка ruSO небезопасна?

Comment: Что касается авторских прав, то вроде бы ничего [из этого](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode.ru) не нарушено.

Comment: Наверное, всё же стоило упомянуть связанный вопрос, тем более, что вы оставили там [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11097/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f/11132?noredirect=1#comment47152_11132)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я верно понял, так нужно сделать? Добавил ссылку в вопросе

Comment: Да-да. Всё верно, так намного понятнее будет непосвящённому читателю.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, спасибо.

Comment: [tag:модераторский-произвол]

Comment: @Barmaley, крайне неудачное решение, которое даже большинством принято не было. Еще более странно, то что старые вопросы-конкурсы тоже сделали общими: это как несение ответственности за нарушение закона, который еще не вступил в силу. Бред какой-то. Верните все как было, будьте добры.

Comment: по-моему тоже это плохой вариант.

Comment: @PashaPash я и не говорил, что имеют.

Comment: "Существует несколько ситуаций, когда вопрос или ответ может автоматически получить статус «общий». В этих случаях, мы верим, что сообщение де-факто является общим:

тело сообщение было отредактировано минимум 5 различными участниками,
сообщение было отредактировано 10 раз автором,
вы отвечаете на общий вопрос,
вопрос получает более 30 ответов" - справка stackOverflow

Comment: @alex9127 Это устаревшие сведения. Раньше при больше 10 правок автоматом присваивало статус "общий", но потом это убрали.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight тогда почему so не отредактирует справку раз это устаревшие сведения?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[модераторский-произвол](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb)

## Я тоже за возвращение вопросов в первоначальное состояние.

Я считаю, что это — неправильно. Сообщество вас выбрало ради "честности и справедливости", который извините, но пока не наблюдается. Вместо этого вы единолично приняли решение отметить "общим" вопросы, хотя большинтво, сообщество (называйте как хотите) было против этой идеи. Она не решает проблему. Она не несет пользы.

Авторские права? Не нарушены? Ну и что?  А как обещалось "по-человечески"?

Присоединяюсь к Севастополю с просьбой вернуть вопросы в первоначальное состояние.

## Update

Благодарю за возвращение вопросов в первоначальное состояние и за понимание. Надеюсь в следующей раз вы будете прислушиваться к мнению сообщества прежде, чем принимать важные решения.

Comment: Victor VosMottor, благодарю вас за поддержку! И конечно же всех, кто считает такое решение несправедливым. Вот когда идет на тебя такая атака несправедливости, волна негатива, то скажу честно: Да, пропадает всякое желание в дальнейшем быть частью этого сообщества и приносить ему пользу. Но всё-таки я верю в лучшее, зная и всегда руководствуясь одним золотым правилом: **Сила в правде. У кого правда, тот и сильнее**. Всем успехов!

Comment: @Sevastopol' Спасибо за такие... мотивирующие слова. Не уходите с ru.SO, вы вносите большой вклад. Сообщество вам благодарно. _Желаю и вам удачи и успехов!_

Comment: Victor VosMottor, отмечаю ваш ответ галочкой, правда я не совсем знаю, как это нужно делать правильно на Мете (нужно ли отмечать или еще как-то в таких случаях). Свой ответ я чуть позже также напишу. Всех хотелось бы поблагодарить за поддержку. Очень важно, чтобы в нашем коллективе всегда принимались только справедливые решения. Тогда и стимул будет к дальнейшему участию в сообществе. Всем желаю успехов!

Comment: @Sevastopol' Я тоже не знаю. Спасибо вам в любом случае. Прошу так же поучаствовать в [голосовании](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11141/%d0%93%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2), чтобы наконецто окончательно закрыть эту тему.

Comment: Я считаю что на SO появилась болезнь с названием придумай SVG анимацию и реализуй. Думаю конфликты по теме SVG неизбежны и ещё будут.

Answer (score 3):

Вопросы возвращены в первоначальное состояние. От себя лично, а также от лица участников, которые публиковали свои ответы, хотел бы поблагодарить всех неравнодушных за поддержку!

Да, это решение модератора @Barmaley♦ было несправедливым. Однако стараюсь верить в то, что в дальнейшем подобных действий не повторится.

Хотелось бы немного прокомментировать [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11137/377637) @Barmaley♦

> ...у многих складывается ощущение, что это была осознанная накрутка
> голосов.

Пожалуйста, не нужно считать так, что если вы так думаете, то значит так думают многие? Каждый должен высказывать исключительно только свое мнение, а не мнение других. Вы меня прямо обвиняете в накрутке голосов? Мною был объявлен конкурс и назначено вознаграждение 500 репутации. Не сложно подсчитать, сколько репутации я отдал и сколько получил. И вам это следовало для начала проанализировать, прежде чем предъявлять такое оскорбительное обвинение.

> В общем то реакция предсказуема. Именно такая редакция ожидалась, она
> была предсказуема.

Ну если для вас это было предсказуемо, тогда вы прекрасно понимали, что вы не правы. Следовательно, какую цель в таком случае вы преследовали, принимая такое решение и действия? Ну явно, раз это не во благо, то очевидно во вред. Тогда это можно расценить как вредительство?

> Заступая на модераторство изначально предупреждал, что со мной
> неудобно.

А собственно почему нам с вами должно быть удобно или неудобно? Раз вы приняли решение быть модератором, то вы не просто должны, более того, вы обязаны принимать справедливые решения согласно установленным сообществом правилам. Участники, голосовавшие за вашу кандидатуру на выборах, на это и рассчитывали, а значит верили вам. Быть модератором это высокая ответственность, это положительный пример для всех участников. И это нужно всегда помнить, прежде чем совершать какие-либо единоличные действия.

> Я против бессмысленных обсуждений, которые не ведут ни к каким
> решениям

Любые обсуждения в сообществе не могут быть бессмысленными. Если и поднимается какая-то тема, значит она актуальна и заслуживает внимания, ее нужно развивать для того, чтобы приходить к какому-то обоюдному решению, которое будет устраивать всех участников. Например, в нашем сообществе, есть участники, которые негативно относятся к некоторым вопросам. Для этого и ведутся обсуждения. И когда-нибудь мы обязательно придем к единому мнению благодаря именно этим, как вы говорите - бессмысленным, обсуждениям.

> ...я по сути своей Лицо Принимающее Решение - и в миру и в быту,
> нравится это кому-то или нет.
>
> Из комментария: *@Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik я имел ввиду, что в миру я
> ЛПР ибо руковожу коллективом под тысячу человек :)*

Ну и что? Ну вот я, например, больше двадцати лет проработал руководителем строительной компании, и в моем подчинении также были немалые коллективы. И что дальше? Как я комментировал выше, здесь в сообществе, вы как модератор, должны принимать справедливые решения согласно установленным нашим сообществом ruSO правилам. А то что за пределами нашего с вами сообщества, это уже ваша личная жизнь, и ваше другое сообщество. У каждого из нас имеется своя личная жизнь, своя работа, и в каждой семье, в каждом рабочем коллективе свои правила, обычаи, устои, нормы поведения. И везде нужно под них подстраиваться, такие вот реалии жизни.

> Принимая решение, я исходил не из интересов ТС или его
> противников/заступников, коих безусловно много, а исходил из интересов
> SO

Принимая такое важное решение, очевидно, что вы плохо изучили поднятую тему. Ну как минимум не пытались ее глубоко изучить.

> Я сделал общим. Откровенно, не вижу здесь особых проблем.

В том-то и дело, что именно вы сделали общим, а не сообщество. Это было ваше единоличное решение, которое, к сожалению, было ошибочным. В ваших руках, как модератора, имеются инструменты (а это некая власть), которые доступны только вам. Так вот некоторыми такими инструментами пользоваться нужно предельно аккуратно, а иначе можно только навредить.

> Свою долю признания ТС уже получил

Расцениваю это как оскорбление, или даже унижение собственного достоинства. И раньше я уже как-то комментировал, что моей целью признание не является. Не по этой причине я состою в нашем сообществе. Целью моей является помощь новичкам, обмен опытом, и не более того.

> ...и на будущее урок тем кто пожелает повторить путь ТС.

Ну слушайте, это уже слишком, звучит как угроза всем участникам сообщества. Вы модератор, а не судья. Вам участники доверяют, ждут от вас помощи и справедливости. А вы в ответ рассылаете угрозы. Это недопустимое поведение!

> ...ваша истерика (зачеркнуто) подтверждает догадки

Принципиально не буду расценивать это как прямое оскорбление, пусть оно, это ваше высказывание и ваши догадки, останутся на вашей совести. Хочется только спросить: а где вы собственно увидели эту самую истерику? Как мне кажется, мною был задан простой и короткий вопрос. У меня к вашему сведению не было истерики даже тогда, когда в прошлом году мне пришлось налог более миллиона рублей государству заплатить с продажи дома. Ну а тут и подавно, даже палец не дрогнул, нажимая на кнопку.

Ну и напоследок, уважаемый @Barmaley♦, мне не хотелось бы с вами ругаться. Напротив, я очень хочу, чтобы у нас с вами сложились крепкие, рабочие, конструктивные, добрые и доверительные взаимоотношения, какие и должны быть между всеми участниками нашего сообщества. Где-то в глубине души мне хотелось бы иметь такие отношения и с Андреем (@andreymal), который периодически не дает покоя некоторым участникам, но и сам плохо спит по ночам, обдумывая, как закрыть и мои в том числе вопросы. Кстати, @Barmaley♦, хочу напомнить вам ваш комментарий, который вы оставили [в этой теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4280/377637) четыре года назад:

> Нет, я не ходок в модераторы - я понял, что это не мое – Barmaley♦ 23
> дек '16 в 20:40

А что поменялось? Четыре года, как мне кажется, срок как бы и не большой для того, чтобы изменить свое мнение для принятия такого важного решения, заявить о готовности, а тем более взять на себя столь сложные обязательства и ответственность модераторства. В любом случае хочу пожелать вам только удачи в этом нелегком деле.

---

Еще раз хочу поблагодарить всех, кто поддержал меня, кто критиковал меня, кто подарил частичку внимания и остался неравнодушным в решении этого вопроса. Очень хочется быть частью этого замечательного сообщества и приносить ему пользу. Я всегда верю в лучшее,  руководствуясь одним золотым правилом: *Сила в правде. У кого правда, тот и сильнее. (Цитата из к/ф Брат)*

Всем желаю успехов!

С уважением, Sevastopol'

Answer (score -19):

К сожалению:

> Stack Overflow Content
> All materials displayed or performed on the public Network, including but not limited to text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, and animations (collectively “Network Content”) (other than Network Content posted by individual “Subscriber Content”) are the property of Stack Overflow and/or third parties and are protected by United States and international copyright laws (“Stack Overflow Content”).

То что вы опубликовали, является не вашей собственностью, а собственностью SO.

[Было обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11097/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f), которое большинством голосов признало, что такие вопросы нарушают правила сообщества, но для того, чтобы сохранить контент, который признается интересным принято решение сделать ваш вопрос общим, иначе у многих складывается ощущение, что это была осознанная накрутка голосов.

**Update**

В общем то реакция предсказуема. Именно такая редакция ожидалась, она была предсказуема. Ну, возможно, пост был написан слегка эмоционально, если причинил неудобства - извиняюсь (скорректировал пост).

Заступая на модераторство изначально предупреждал, что со мной неудобно. Я против бессмысленных обсуждений, которые не ведут ни к каким решениям, я по сути своей [Лицо Принимающее Решение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BE,_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) - и в миру и в быту, нравится это кому-то или нет.

Принимая решение, я исходил не из интересов ТС или его противников/заступников, коих безусловно много, а исходил из интересов SO. Альтернативы были:

1. Оставить все как есть и превратить множество постов в поле адской брани
2. Удалить пост или закрыть
3. Сделать общим

Я сделал общим. Откровенно, не вижу здесь особых проблем. Свою долю признания ТС уже получил, хейтеры ТС также получили то что хотели (частично безусловно, ибо настаивали вообще на удалении поста) и на будущее урок тем кто пожелает повторить путь ТС.

Делайте нормальные конкурсы согласно правилам сообщества и все.

Засим, позвольте откланяться.

Comment: но большинство пользователей были против [вашего предложения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11132/400096)

Comment: "То что вы опубликовали, является не вашей собственностью, а собственностью SO." - право собственности не имеет прямого отношения к авторству, и тем более не имеет отношения к тому, начислять ли виртуальные очки за созданный контент конкретному участнику. Вы приняли решение эти очки забрать, хотя сообщество явно против.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @PashaPash. Поставил тревогу на ответе за "истерику". Это уже перебор. Сообщество с вашим единоличным решением не согласно, верните вопросы в первоначальное состояние. P. S. Сообщение модератора, заслуживающее тревоги -- не думал, что до такого докатимся.

Comment: Хоть я и не сторонние подобных конкурсов, но @Sevastopol' вложил в этот вопрос свой труд, который сообщество по достоинству оценило, и обвинять его в накрутке репутации -- как минимум несправедливо и глупо.

Comment: @eanmos В этом обвинении нет ничего глупого. Sevastopol уже блокировали за накрутку репутации в мае. Это может быть и не было связано напрямую с конкурсами, но позволило сделать определенные выводы.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, я говорю о том, что текущая ситуация не является накруткой репутации, если я правильно понимаю значение "накрутки". Если человек написал вопрос и ответил на него, а другие пользователи проголосовали -- является ли это накруткой? По-моему нет.

Comment: @eanmos публикация контента, который недостаточно однозначно вписывается в текущую схему, но предсказуемо будет воспринят позитивно голосами масс, особо не вникающих в действующие ограничения, может в некоторой мере рассматриваться как накрутка (более простой способ получить голоса, нежели действуя по классической схеме - отвечая на ответы других и задавая вопросы для получения ответов от других участников). Можно вспомнить [диалоги-о-работе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5812/176217). Они были восприняты с интересом (читай как получили голоса), но по сути являются неформатом.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, это уже другой вопрос: с какой целью Sevastopol' опубликовал эти посты. Кроме того, он не считает, что они неоднозначно вписываются в правила SO. И в таком случае обвинения в накрутке должны распространятся на всех отвечающих на подобные вопросы. В любом случае это будет накруткой только есль целью создания таких постов является более простое получение репутации. Узнать так это или нет не представляется возможным, поэтому я и назвал обвинения в накрутке -- глупыми и несправедливыми. Несправедливыми -- потому что они не доказаны, глупыми -- потому что доказать их нельзя.

Comment: "я по сути своей Лицо Принимающее Решение". Выглядит больше как вахтёрство.

Comment: Спасибо за апдейт. По поводу конкурсов - поддерживаю. Они, конечно, развлекают народ, но при этом сильно ломают всю идею репутации.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik я имел ввиду, что в миру я ЛПР ибо руковожу коллективом под тысячу человек :)

Comment: @Barmaley, не знаю где вы такие интересы SO увидели. По-моему, сообщество ясно дало понять (по голосам за сообщение), что это решение его не устраивает.

Comment: Что касается накрутки голосов, то это очень сомнительное обвинение. Нужно учитывать, что был объявлен конкурс и назначено награждение 500 репутации. Не сложно подсчитать, сколько было отдано и сколько получено. А по поводу моей блокировки за накрутку еще весной, то здесь у меня есть еще много вопросов, которые для меня до сих пор остаются загадкой.

Comment: Это не накрутка голосов. Накрутка голосов это например использовать сокпаппет и голосовать из него за свой аккаунт, но не написать хороший вопрос и получить справедливые, честные голоса от обычных участников.

Comment: Вы выбрали нечто среднее, а это называется не нашим, не вашим уж извините. Вам никто не давал прав злоупотреблять модераторской позицией и помечать вопрос общим против воли автора вопроса и главное — сообщества.

Comment: И уж если "закон" хотите, то помимо реальных прав, есть закон виртуальный, который вы нарушили сейчас.

Comment: @Barmaley так уж принято, что закон обратной силы не имеет. Залочили бы старые, а новые делали "общими".

Comment: Ох уж это большинство) А давно у нас тут демократия?

Comment: @vp_arth (¬‿¬ )

Comment: Мне кажется что svg-анимация заняла какую-то странную нишу, на которой учасники поднимают кучу репутации. Я считаю несправедливым зароботок очков на svg, почему то тема с svg тут оценивается по факту "дороже" чем c++ c# python php и другие. Либо несколько учасников svg (более 100) держат круговую поруку, либо svg действительно настолько востребован и нужен обществу, но не мне. Я склоняюсь к первому. Думаю конфликты с svg ещё будут, я сам писал уже на мете про svg.

Comment: Появилась болезь: 1. Придумаем картинку 2. придумаем как её анимировать. 3. Составим вопрос. 4. Составим ответ. 5. Получим балы. По такому рецепту один из учасников уже набрал 100к репы за год или меньше. Это на фоне других тем выглядит странно. Может давайте все вместе сочинять картиночки и публиковать на SO - посмотрим чем закончится? Как по мне - фантазии должно хватить на много изображений.

Comment: Вот я писал про SVG https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6918/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2 и сейчас ничего не поменялось. SVG стал хорошим способом легально поднять балов. Почему так получилось - не знаю. Считают ли это остальные учасники справедливым - я думаю что нет. Поэтому конфликты по метке SVG неизбежны.

Comment: @Danis я не думаю что админ решил играть на стороне противников SVG, я думаю что любители SVG как только увидели пост, то сделали из положительного голосования отрицательные поставив минусов штук 30. Хотелось бы знать сколько набрал ответ по ссылке до минусования.Думаю тамбыл положительный балланс доопредёленного времени Я думаю это сговор любителей SVG против того что бы их мутки были исправлены вмешательством администратора. Я не вижу ничего крамольного в сообщениях администратора, считаю цифру -14 и т п просто перевесом к-ва людей с заинтерисованой стороны, а не реальным мнением сообщества.

Comment: @nick_n_a в самом начале был один голос «за», но после этого постепенно рейтинг шёл в минус